# apache solr result logged users node should appear on top and then other user's node

Tags: search

I am using apache solr modules. My requirement was if I hit the search logged in user node should appear on top and then other user's node. How to achieve this requirement. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using the [Apache Solr View module](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views), with this module installed it is only a matter of indexing the correct data and building the view with the correct sorting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just want to know how can I index logged in user's node and sorting the result. For example If I hit the search means I receives 10 node's in the result. I was the author of 2 nodes in that search result. My requirement was my node should appear on the top and the other user's node should appear on subsequent results.

Comment: so you want to group by the user?